# D3.JS add class to each country

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using this for a simple visualisation.

http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/5994804

I want to add the country's name to each path. I've tried to loop over countries, but I have no idea how to link with the SVG.

```
var world = svg.selectAll("path.land")
            .data(countries)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "land")
            .attr("d", path)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Add another class to the generated paths or add text on the globe?

Comment: I want to add class to the path, for example <path class="land india" d="..."> http://jsfiddle.net/7buzp4ab/ here you have the code live

Comment: This would be simply `.attr("class", function(d) { return "land " + d.properties.name; })`, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a function to build the `class` attribute dynamically for each data item:

```
var world = svg.selectAll("path.land")
            .data(countries)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "land " + d.name })
            .attr("d", path)
```

Comment: @Marius: Only a function call the current object `d`, from which you then can call any key-value.